# Beginner Q re: catkin_make of turtlesim (hydro)

Tags: ros, catkin-make, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS, and have been going through the tutorials.  I decided I wanted to modify the behaviour of the Turtlesim demo application (having gotten the source from GitHub).  I wanted to try 'catkin_make' using a target that has a bit more meat than the original example in 
ROS / Tutorials / BuildingPackages. I increased the precision of 'Pi' and made some changes to the 'draw_square' publisher.

The files I got from GIT are located in a folder inside my home directory.  But 'catkin_make' gives an error when I try to make the project.
I've tried copying the files over to the /opt/ros/hydro/share/turtlesim folder and using catkin_make there, but I get the same error as before.

The error I'm getting is:

```
The specified base path "/opt/ros/hydro/share/turtlesim" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace
```

From what I gather about ROS from the tutorials I've been through, I believe I am in the root of the workspace, and the parent folder is 'share'. I have tried 'catkin_init_workspace' and I get a message the CMakeLists.txt already exists.  'rospack find turtlesim' locates the project in /opt/ros/...  so ros knows about my project.

Could someone please explain the above error and what I need to do in response.

Cheers,
Nap

I'm not privileged enough to post a link that points to the same domain where I'm posting. :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108316/beginner-q-re:-catkin_make-of-turtlesim-(hydro)/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your description I guess you are trying to invoke `catkin_make` in the folder where you checked out turtlesim. Instead you should create a workspace (as described here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) and checkout the packages under the `src` subfolder (as described here http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace).

You should never try to build under /opt/ros/*. Always create and build your workspace somewhere in your home folder.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2013-12-09**:
@Dirk, thanks.  Copying to /opt/ros/...  was an attempt to overcome the error.
Now that I've compiled it, how do I install it to /opt/ros/... so I can replace the original turtlesim?  I used the "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro" option but it still went into the workspace's install folder.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2013-12-09**:
Got it....  'source setup.sh' in the workspace's install folder did the trick.